# Cocos2d and UIKit animations not in sync

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, uiviewanimation

I'm trying to animate a Cocos2d node and a UIKit view move like this:

```
-(void)someFunction {
    [myCocosNode runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:myTime position:cocosPoint]];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:myTime animations:^{ myView.frame = CGRectMake(uiPoint.x, uiPoint.y, myWidth, myHeight); }];
}
```

But the UIKit view doesn't move at the same speed as the Cocos2d node, and they are in the same starting position going to the same ending position.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cocos2d based on OpenGL ES + timer, UiKit have own implementation. I think you couldn't sync them. Try to test this animation on device, simulator could lag.

Comment: The best I've been able to come up with is to set the animation curve to linear for UIKit, and just play with the time until it looks close.  Doesn't look the best though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works for synchronizing movement [by PhilM in this thread.](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/2415)

He attaches the UIView to a subclass of CCLayer and overrides `setPosition:` to update the `UIView`'s position when the layer moves.  Then using `CCMoveTo` on the layer will synchronize the movement with the `UIView`.

```
-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)pos {
    [super setPosition:pos];

   CGRect frame = slider.frame;
   frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + ([self position].y - pos.y); // Changed this line a bit to get correct positioning
   slider.frame = frame;
}
```

Thanks PhilM!

Comment: Note: The same thing can be applied to fading!